# Cannot expand shortcuts using SHBrowseForFolder function in Windows 8.1

Tags: c++, windows, file

I have 2 cpp GUI applications P1 and P2. P1 can be opened by two ways.

1. Through directly double clicking or using command line
2. Using P2's GUI, implemented using the `CreateProcess` function (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx), using default flags.

P1 has a file selection box, which is implemented using `SHBrowseForFolder` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762115(v=vs.85).aspx), using default flags.

In windows 8.1 the file selection box shows several shortcuts under 'This PC' dropdown (Desktop, Pictures, Downloads etc).

If I use method 1 to open P1 these shortcuts expand fine.
But if I use method 2, while expanding these shortcuts it shows the following error in a dialogue box.

> C:\Windows\system32\config\systemprofile\Desktop refers to a location that is unavailable. It could be on a hard drive on this computer or on a network. Check to make sure that the disk is properly inserted, or that you are connected to the Internet or your network, then try again. If it still cannot be located, the information might have been moved to a different location

Please help guys. Stuck in this for last two days.

EDIT: Just found out the following.
Process P2 is opened by a system level process in the start up. If I close P2 and reopens it as a user, error is gone ,the file selection works fine.

Comment: There is something drastically wrong with the user account that you use to start this process.  Never use the LocalSystem account, it does not have a profile that's suitable for the shell dialogs (as you found out) and you expose yourself to nasty shatter attacks.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Both P1 and P2 runs under current user account, not under SYSTEM. I checked in task manager. Session id in also 1 for both.

Comment: Is there a way to hide those folders under This PC when dialogue box is opened?

Answer (score 0):

Found out the issue. I was creating processes using CreateProcess function with default flags. One of the argument is environmental block, for which I passed NULL. So the new process will be created with parent processes environmental variable. So in the startup P2 is created by a system level process with environmental variables of system. Ans P2 will create P1 with same environmental variables. So when expanding shortcuts P1 will look for the USERPROFILE variable in the environmental block, which will be systemprofile. 
When I open P2 as a user environmental variables are set correctly and shortcuts expands properly.
May this be helpful for someone in future.